# Prove that $\gcd(P, P')$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb R.$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Let $P(X)$ = $X^4 + 2X^3 + 3X^2 + 2X + 1$

Let $P'$ be the derivative of $P$.

1. Factor $P$ as a product of irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb R$.
2. Find all the real and complex roots of $P$. What are their multiplicities?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Common roots of a polynomial $P$ and its derivative  are multiple roots of $P$, i.e. roots of order  $\ge 2$. Now $P$ has degree $2$ and the g.c.d. of $P$ and $P'$, which yields the (complex) multiple roots has degree $2$. Do you see what you can deduce?

Comment: Not sure, is that related to point 2?

Comment: No, it's related to points 3 and 4. Point 2 is easy, since the roots of the g.c.d. are well-known complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $P$ = $(x^2+x+1)^2$ and roots are cube roots of $1$ with multiplicity $2$.